# Dynamic planningVariable with rangeProvider

Tags: optaplanner

I try to keep the domain for my problem as simple as possible:

I have jobs with jobSteps. The job needs a start time and the jobSteps have different machines, process times and an allowed overprocesstime. But the maximal overprocesstime is different for each job or even 0 (not allowed).

now the jobs should be scheduled with some conditions:
once a job started it have to be finished without any pause (each step must be worked through)
The jobs should be startet as soon as possible.

So i have two planning Variables: start time of the job and the usedOverprocessTime for the jobstep
(it can make sense to overprocess some jobs - cause the next machine is still working a short time on an other job)

simple example:
job 1: {[machine: A, processTime: 80, allowedOverprocessTime: 20], [machine: B, processTime: 80, allowedOverprocessTime: 0], [machine: C, processTime: 100, allowedOverprocessTime: 30]}

job 2: {[machine: A, processTime: 50, allowedOverprocessTime: 10], [machine: B, processTime: 80, allowedOverprocessTime: 30], [machine: C, processTime: 100, allowedOverprocessTime: 30]}

[image]

The code for the start time of the jobs is kinda simple:

```
@PlanningEntity
@Entity
public class Job {
   ...
   @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "jobStartTimeRange")
   private Integer jobStartTime;
```

and then i have a planningsolution class:

```
@PlanningSolution
public class JobSchedule {
    ...
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "jobStartTimeRange")
    public List<Integer> createStartTimeList() {
        // here i calculate a worst case range if the jobs have to 
        // be worked on one after the other without overlapping
    }
```

sofar this should work. now the problem with the overprocess time:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class JobStep {
    ...
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "plannedOverprocessTimeRange")
    public Integer plannedOverprocessTime = 0;
```

for the provider i would need the current step to return an individual range from 0 to the specific max value. I even had the idea of returning a Map<JobStep, List> so each step could lookup the specific range. But the annotation is only for collections.

so is it somehow possible to create the ranges for the planningvariable dynamic like i need to? I would be surprised if i were the first to have this request to be honest.

Comment: i just had the idea to provide the max allowed overprocesstime in the provider and add an hard constraint for each job step that the used overprocesstime must less or equal to the max allowed overprocess time for the jobstep - but those big range for each step would give a much bigger calculation base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OptaPlanner supports a wide range of [`ValueRangeProvider`](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#planningValueRangeProvider) implementations, and it also allows you to implement your own. The question does not make it clear whether you've already tried this mechanism and it didn't work for your use case, or if you're not aware of this functionality at all.

My interpretation is that, if you put a `ValueRangeProvider` on your planning entity, you will be able to do what you need.

Comment: thanks i think this is what i needed - the hint :This annotation can be located on two types of methods:
On the Solution: All planning entities share the same value range.
On the planning entity: The value range differs per planning entity. This is less common.

Comment: If it works for you, please consider accepting the answer. :-)

Comment: i cant get my code running but im pretty sure that is what i was looking for :)